# How to use UICollectionview Controller as a master view in split view controller of ipad?

Tags: uicollectionview, ipad

I've seen some examples of using UICollectionview controller for a detail view.
But I never seen UICollectionview controller for a master view in split view of ipad.
Does anyone know the answer?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Actually the notions of "master view" and "detail view" are purely conventional. A split view controller is simply a view controller with a certain way of displaying two view controller children. If you want a UICollectionViewController to be the first of those children rather than the second one, go right ahead.

However, it sounds like you'll be happier designing your own custom parent view controller. UISplitViewController doesn't do anything that you can't do yourself, and you can probably do it better.